# How can I receive my REST API errors and place them on the form quickly?

Tags: angular, typescript

## The problem

In my application the form errors are handled from the REST API, for example the password is very similar to the username, or for example the username field is missing in the registry.

The problem is that this requires a lot of code for each form, it is not difficult, but I would like to know if there is another way to do it without having to create a model for errors and with less code

## The current code

#### SigininComponent

**siginin-form.component.html**

```
<form #newUserForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username" class="col-form-label">Nombre de usuario</label>
                    <input id="username" type="email" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" [(ngModel)]="newUser.username" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && error.username }" name="username"/>
                    <div *ngIf="error.username" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="error.username">{{error.username}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <label for="email" class="col-form-label">Correo Electronico</label>
                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" autocomplete="email" [(ngModel)]="newUser.email" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && error.email }" name="email"/>
                    <div *ngIf="error.email" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="error.email">{{error.email}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <label for="first-name" class="col-form-label">Nombre</label>
                    <input id="first-name" type="email" class="form-control" autocomplete="given-name" [(ngModel)]="newUser.first_name" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && error.first_name }" name="first_name"/>
                    <div *ngIf="error.first_name" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="error.first_name">{{error.first_name}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <label for="last-name" class="col-form-label">Apellidos</label>
                    <input id="last-name" type="email" class="form-control" autocomplete="family-name" [(ngModel)]="newUser.last_name" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && error.last_name }" name="last_name"/>
                    <div *ngIf="error.last_name" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="error.last_name">{{error.last_name}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="col-form-label">Contraseña</label>
                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="newUser.password" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && error.password }" name="password"/>
                    <div *ngIf="error.password" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="error.password">{{error.password}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <label for="password_confirm" class="col-form-label">Confirmacion contraseña</label>
                    <input id="password_confirm" type="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="newUser.password_confirm" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && error.password_confirm }" name="password_confirm"/>
                    <div *ngIf="error.password_confirm" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="error.password_confirm">{{error.password_confirm}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span *ngIf="loading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
                    Registrarme
                </button>
                <div *ngIf="error.general" class="alert alert-danger mt-3 mb-0">{{error.general}}</div>
            </form>
```

**siginin-form.component.ts**

```
export class SigininFormComponent implements OnInit {

    newUser: NewUser = new NewUser();
    submitted = false;
    loading = false;
    error: ErrorSiginin = new ErrorSiginin();

    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    onSubmit() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.submitted = true;

        this.userService.siginin(this.newUser.username, this.newUser.first_name, this.newUser.last_name,
            this.newUser.email, this.newUser.password, this.newUser.password_confirm)
            .subscribe(data => {

            }, err => {

                console.log(err);

                if (err.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
                    err.error.hasOwnProperty('username') ? this.error.username = `${err.error.username}` : this.error.username = '';
                    err.error.hasOwnProperty('email') ? this.error.email = `${err.error.email}` : this.error.email = '';
                    err.error.hasOwnProperty('first_name') ? this.error.first_name = `${err.error.first_name}` : this.error.first_name = '';
                    err.error.hasOwnProperty('last_name') ? this.error.last_name = `${err.error.last_name}` : this.error.last_name = '';
                    err.error.hasOwnProperty('password') ? this.error.password = `${err.error.password}` : this.error.password = '';
                    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
                    err.error.hasOwnProperty('password_confirm') ? this.error.password_confirm = `${err.error.password_confirm}` : this.error.password_confirm = '';
                    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
                    err.error.hasOwnProperty('non_field_errors') ? this.error.general = `${err.error.non_field_errors}` : this.error.general = '';
                }
                console.log(this.error);
                this.loading = false;
            });
    }

}
```

**ErrorSiginin.ts (the error model)**

```
export class ErrorSiginin {
    username: string;

    // tslint:disable-next-line:variable-name
    first_name: string;
    // tslint:disable-next-line:variable-name
    last_name: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    // tslint:disable-next-line:variable-name
    password_confirm: string;
    general: string;

    constructor() {
        this.username = '';
        this.first_name = '';
        this.last_name = '';
        this.email = '';
        this.password = '';
        this.password_confirm = '';
        this.general = '';
    }

}
```

## In conclusion

I want to get the errors of each element of the form that my API returns but the way I have to do it now is very tedious and repetitive (as you can see in the code).

I can't think of another way to do it, and my knowledge of angular at the moment is limited

**I need each error string separately to place it under each form entry**

## Tests:

I have tried to directly assign the error as follows:

I declare the error object as:

```
error: any;
```

and then I assign the error when the REST API returns it to me like this:

```
onSubmit() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.submitted = true;

        this.userService.siginin(this.newUser.username, this.newUser.first_name, this.newUser.last_name,
            this.newUser.email, this.newUser.password, this.newUser.password_confirm)
            .subscribe(data => {

            }, err => {

                this.error = err.error;
                this.loading = false;
            });
    }
```

Unfortunately that throws me the following exception:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (SigininFormComponent.html:9)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:39364)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:38376)
    at callViewAction (core.js:38742)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:38670)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:38383)
    at callViewAction (core.js:38742)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:38699)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:38377)
    at callViewAction (core.js:38742)
```

the html code is not modified in this test

## The solution!

As Andy Seymour said:
I only need to assign the error object that returns the request to my error object, therefore the code is as follows:

```
export class SigininFormComponent implements OnInit {

newUser: NewUser = new NewUser();
submitted = false;
loading = false;
error: ErrorSiginin = new ErrorSiginin();
constructor(private userService: UserService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
}

onSubmit() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.submitted = true;

    this.userService.siginin(this.newUser.username, this.newUser.first_name, this.newUser.last_name,
        this.newUser.email, this.newUser.password, this.newUser.password_confirm)
        .subscribe(data => {

        }, err => {

            console.log(err);
            this.error = err.error;

            this.loading = false;
        });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd store the error object as it is (don't try and see if the properties exist) and if the key is defined then use that error
i.e `<div *ngIf="error.password">{{error.password}}</div>`

Also use an `ng-repeat` to display your fields. This will make the whole thing scalable if you add more fields.

If the fields need to be different or have different props, then define schema for each one like;

```
username: {
 type: string,
 ...otherDetails
}
```

Comment: When I directly assign the error I get the following error: **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined** 
I will edit the post to better explain how I tried it. Sorry if I am not understanding what you want to tell me ...

Comment: ok, I've been able to make it work, I just need to declare error as type "ErrorSiguinin".

I update my post with the most developed solution and mark your answer as the one that solved my problem